# windws 7 download has 2 files, .iso and .dlm

Tags: windows-7, download, iso-image

If I have a .dlm file in my windows 7 download folder, does this mean it didn't complete?

The .iso is 1 gig and the .dlm is 3 gigs.

**Update**

Ok I downloaded it AGAIN and same thing.  That lame java download manager is not combing the file, it says 100%?

Answer (score 2):

You must have had an issue downloading it, try deleting those files and redownloading.

Also you may want to try the high speed links for MSDN or TechNet:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/08/06/Windows-7-RTM-is-on-MSDN-TechNet-e28093-Heree28099s-the-AKAMAI-links!.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you downloaded this ISO file with a download manager - possibly [Akamai Download Manager](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/dlm)?

And yes, it would appear the download didn't complete, or for some reason didn't combine the two files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 7 is approximately 4GB in size and it seems that your download manager has created a temporary file to add the already downloaded part to.

Try downloading again, or if your manager allows it, resume the download.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN and MS VLM download sites both use a fairly lame (as in rarely works properly to download a full file in my experience) download manager, that downloads the files via Akamai.

If you connect to either site with IE6 or 7 (haven't tried with 8) and try downloading large files (the threshold seems to be somewhere around 1GB) it will say that your web browser can't direct download the file and your only option is their download manager.

However, if you connect with Firefox (only tried with v3+) it will generally give you the option to direct download from the webpage and downloads the whole thing in one go as a normal web browser download, which in my experience, is far more reliable.